# Kendo UI for Asp .Net core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

Is Kendo UI works with asp .Net core 2.0 ?

If yes, can anyone have any demo on this. As, I am trying to use Kendo UI  for my asp .net core 2.0 project and I am getting some issue there.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions from this [Getting Started article](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/getting-started/getting-started) worked at my side for ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The followings are the steps -

- Use [offline NuGet package](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit#troubleshooting) for server-side wrapper
- Copy Kendo client-side libraries inside `wwwroot/lib/kendo-ui/`
- Finally, refrence those in `_Layout.cshtml`

### Inside `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<environment names="Development">
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    ...
    <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
    ...
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="k-common-test-class"
          asp-fallback-test-property="opacity"
          asp-fallback-test-value="0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles//kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="k-theme-test-class"
          asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" 
          asp-fallback-test-value="0"/>
    ...    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.kendo">
    </script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']">
    </script>
    ...
</environment>
```

I have a sample project in [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit) which happens to use Kendo UI. I also use server-side wrapper, but I could not check-in to public repository due to licensing restriction.

Answer (score 0):

The method is same as we use in .Net core 1.So,follow the steps that we are using in .Net core 1 for Kendo setup.